# Objectify LoadException (after upgrading V4.1.3 to V5) Expected property value but found...

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I have an entity with an embedded entity.

```
@Entity @Cache public class UserOFY implements Serializable {
     @Id @Index private Long id;        
     @Unindex public LessonScheduleOFY lessonSchedule;
}

@Entity public class LessonScheduleOFY implements IsSerializable, Serializable {
     @Id @Index private Long id;

}
```

In Objectify V4.1.3, if I tag the LessonScheduleOFY with @Embed, it works fine.

```
   @Embed @Entity public class LessonScheduleOFY implements IsSerializable, Serializable {
         @Id @Index private Long id;
    }
```

When I try to upgrade to V5, I run `ofy().factory().setSaveWithNewEmbedFormat(true);`

and then load my `UserOFY` entities, and save the `LessonScheduleOFY` entities as well as the `UserOFY` entities.

However, when I change to V5 (removing V4 from my classpath) and remove the @Embed tag, I get an error:

> Caused by: com.googlecode.objectify.LoadException: Error loading
>   UserOFY(19001): At path 'lessonSchedule': Expected property value but
>   found: {reviewing={true}, index={1}, completedLessons={}, timesAllCompleted={0}, ongoingReviewSchedule={}, revScheduleQueueResetSize={4}, ongoingReviewStats={}, id={19001}, reviewScheduleQueue={},
>   reviewSchedule={}, lessonSchedule=[{911}, {912},
>   {2676}, {2681}, {2696}, {2699}, {2700}, {12001}, {14001}, {17001},
>   {4644337115725824}, {4785074604081152}, {5207287069147136},
>   {5348024557502464}, {5910974510923776}, {6192449487634432},
>   {6333186975989760}, {5488762045857792}, {6614661952700416}],
>   nextScheduledLesson={912}, completedLessonDate={},
>   READY_TO_ADVANCE={true}}

Questions:

1) can things like `@com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Serialize private HashMap<Long, Long> completedLessonDate;` not be used in an embedded class in V5?

2) If I can't find a way to use LessonScheduleOFY as an embedded class anymore, how can I migrate it to it's own Entity?  Use `Ref<?>s` and @Load? to form a Relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The embedded entity didn't have an @Id annotation which is needed.

I took StickFigure's advice (in comment below) and simply removed the @Entity and @Id annotations.

Comment: Alternatively, you could have dropped the `@Entity` and `@Id` annotations. Embedded things don't need to be /entities/ per-se.